# Database transactions don't work in codeception Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, transactions, laravel-5, codeception

I am trying to work with database transactions in Laravel 5 using Codeception to test my API. The Laravel 5 module [documentation](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5#.Vl6PVFgrL3U) says clearly states in the config section:

> cleanup: boolean, default true - all db queries will be run in
>   transaction, which will be rolled back at the end of test.

My **codeception.yml** file looks like so:

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=carparts'
            user: 'root'
            password: 'password'
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
```

My **api.suite.yml** file looks like so:

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Laravel5
        - Db
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/api'
            curl:
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: true
        - REST:
            url: http://localhost:8000/api/
            depends: Laravel5
    config:
        Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.testing
        Db:
            cleanup: false
            populate: false
```

Here I have made the `Db` module `cleanup` and `populate` set to `false` so that the `dump` is not used and instead the database `transactions` from the `Laravel5` module are reversing the `Db` state.

Now here is a simple test:

```
<?php 

changeToTenantDb('carparts');
$I = new ApiTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('create a new comment');
$I->useToken();
$I->sendPost('comments', [
    "document_id" => "1",
    "comment_type_id" => "1",
    "user_id" => "1",
    "body" => "Testing"
]);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
$I->seeResponseContainsJson(['status' => 'success']);
$I->seeInDatabase('comment', [
    "document_id" => "1",
    "comment_type_id" => "1",
    "user_id" => "1",
    "body" => "Testing"
]);
```

It basically persist a comment in the Db and performs basic assertions on the API response and finally checks to see if the record actually did persist in the Db. When I run this, it runs fine and comes back green. But I check the Db and the comment still persists. I run it again, I see another new comment. According to my understand, after the test has finished running, the Db transactions should roll back to the original state. What am I doing wrong?

Moreover if I run the tests like so:

```
sudo codecept run api CreateCommentCept
```

It runs fine. But when I run them together:

```
sudo codecept run api
```

All tests fail. I am totally confused why this is happening. When I change my REST dependency to PhpBrowser instead of Laravel5 module, this does not happen.

PS: I am using Codeception (2.1.3)

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that might be of help  [Laravel5 Module: disable cleanup #2525](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2525)

here janhenkgerritsen commented

> The $config variable of the Laravel 5 module is public, so you can
>   change the cleanup entry in this array yourself by adding a helper.
>   That will work for you now. And I will add the proposed methods to the
>   module when I have some time.

and

> After some thinking I decided not to add methods to the module to
>   disable/enable cleanup. The use case is pretty rare in my opinion, and
>   if you do run into it, you can easily change the behavior with a
>   helper.

**I recommend you to do in the way janhenkgerritsen mentioned in his comment.I  don't recommend editing vendor files but what i did for the time being is**

to find *vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Module/Laravel5.php* and edited following code. changed the `cleanup` to `false`

```
$this->config = array_merge(
            [
                'cleanup' => false,
                'environment_file' => '.env',
                'bootstrap' => 'bootstrap' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'app.php',
                'root' => '',
                'packages' => 'workbench',
                'disable_middleware' => false,
                'disable_events' => false,
            ],
            (array)$config
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding `cleanup: false`, here is my `integration.suite.yml` example:

```
# Unit Test Suite Configuration
#
actor: UnitTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Laravel5:
            environment_file: .env.testing
            cleanup: false
        - Asserts
        - Mockery
        - \Helper\Unit
        - \Helper\JsonLoader
```

and run `./vendor/bin/codecept build` after that!